# Uniform convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For every $r>0,$ the series $f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$. May I know how to **prove/disprove** that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: The terms $(-1)^n{x^{2n}\over n!}$ do not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\Bbb R$. Consequently, the series is not uniformly Cauchy, thus not uniformly convergent, on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I'm not sure if your estimate holds. But observe that for any $n$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f_n(x)|=\infty$. This shows $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The limiting function is $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ which is bounded, while each partial sum is a polynomial - which is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

We know that if  $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} $ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!} \to 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}.$


Since $\|f_n-0\|_\mathbb{R} \geq x^2,$ it follows that $f_n \nrightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo What do you mean by $\| f_n-0 \|_\mathbb{R} \geq x^2$? what is $x$?

Comment: I'm sorry, there is a mistake.Let  $f_n(x)=(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$.  For each $n\in \mathbb{N},$ $|f_n(x)-0| \geq \frac{x^2}{n!}$. For a fixed $n,$ since $lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2}{n!} = \infty, $ it follows that $\|f_n-0\|_\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded and hence $\|f_n-0\|_\mathbb{R} \nrightarrow 0?$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo I think you meant $x^{2n}$ rather than $x^2$. Besides that it looks fine.

Comment: I think it is still the same since $x^{2n} \geq x^2, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo What if $|x|<1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This Taylorseries is recognizable as function $e^{-x^{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if $(p_n)$ is a [sequence of polynomials converging uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453714/f-is-approximated-uniformly-on-r-by-p-nx-then-f-is-a-polynomial) to a function $f$, then $f$ itself is a polynomial. In particular, a power series converges uniformly on $\mathbf{R}$ if and only if the series has only finitely many non-zero terms.

Briefly, $(p_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $\mathbf{R}$, so there exists an $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $|p_n(x) − p_N(x)| < 1$ for all real $x$. That is, $p_n  − p_N$ is a bounded polynomial, i.e., a constant.